# Twitter Boostrap wtih tabs_on_rails or tabulous and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, twitter-bootstrap

Any practical advice or experience on integration of tabs_on_rails or tabulous and devise with Twitter Bootstrap? I'm starting a new project and would like to pick a tab navigation gem. I'v started to experiment with formtastic-bootstrap as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created tabulous and would like for it to work well with devise.  I recently threw together an example app with tabulous with devise and didn't come across any obvious incompatibilities between the two.  If there are any issues with using devise with tabulous I'd like to know about them so that I can fix them.

Comment: No, I haven't tried integrating with formtastic-bootstrap.  I assume you know about this resource? http://rubysource.com/too-good-to-be-true-twitter-bootstrap-meets-formtastic-and-tabulous/